# AD: Group does not have a primaryGroupToken attribute

Tags: .net, vb.net, active-directory, directoryservices

I need to change the primary group of a user, so I can delete it from it's current one. But my group does not have the attribute "primaryGroupToken", which I need in order to change the primary group of the user. Here is a screenshot of the attribute editor:

[image]

Obviously, my code responds nothing:

[image]

```
Dim domainGroup As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://our.domain/CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=our,DC=domain")
Dim domainGroupGroupToken As String = domainGroup.Properties("primaryGroupToken").Value.ToString()
```

Is there a way to manually set it? Or is there something wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a computed property. Stealing from [here](http://microsoft.public.adsi.general.narkive.com/EtZusqyS/how-get-primarygrouptoken-using-c), you just need to add a call to [`RefreshCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/913td91k.aspx) before accessing the property:

```
Dim domainGroup As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://our.domain/CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=our,DC=domain")
domainGroup.RefreshCache(New String() {"primaryGroupToken"})
Dim domainGroupGroupToken As String = domainGroup.Properties("primaryGroupToken").Value.ToString()
```

(Not tested, my VB is a bit rusty)