# How to retrieve group by primaryGroupToken from Active Directory using PHP?

Tags: php, search, active-directory

How can i retrieve a group by it's primaryGroupToken from Active Directory using PHP? Apparently this is a computed attribute so retrieving it is not straight forward, as eluded to in this answer: [AD: Group does not have a primaryGroupToken attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827491/ad-group-does-not-have-a-primarygrouptoken-attribute)

Essentially i'm using the following command:

```
ldap_search(
    $connection,
    "DC=host,DC=only,DC=network",
    "(&(objectClass=group)(objectCategory=group)(primaryGroupToken=513))",
    array("dn", "primarygrouptoken")
)
```

Which results in an error:

```
Warning: ldap_search(): Search: Inappropriate matching
```

Any idea how to retrieve a group using it's primary group token from Active Directory using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way from the linked answer's [reference](http://microsoft.public.adsi.general.narkive.com/EtZusqyS/how-get-primarygrouptoken-using-c) is to request the group by the digits after the final - in the objectsid as the filter parameter.

```
"(&(objectClass=group)(objectCategory=group)(objectSid=*-513))"
```

Attributes parameter would also become `array("dn", "objectSid")`.

Unfortunately this isn't possible as the objectSid as you say in your comment is an OctetString or Byte Array rather than SDDL string. You could search for a specific group by use the escaped (prefixed with \ and in hex) byte string, but that isn't what the question asks.

However binary filters don't support wildcard.
An alternative is to request all groups and then unpack the objectSid for each group and then group by the RID after post processing, however depending on the number of groups in your domain, this may be too slow.

And example of conversion between octet string and SDDS in PHP is located [here](http://blogs.freebsdish.org/tmclaugh/2010/07/21/finding-a-users-primary-group-in-ad/), along with looking up users by PrimaryGroupId.

Another alternative is to use ADO as per [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321360?ln=en) or [here](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Windows/microsoft.public.windows.server.scripting/2007-03/msg00003.html) but this requires [ADODB](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/).

Also see [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ad1396f1-a951-4a28-9a35-e2c5d9a2b22f/finding-primary-group-of-users-in-ad?forum=winserverDS) for a second reference. 
Additional References [here](http://www.selfadsi.org/deep-inside/microsoft-sid-attributes.htm) and [here](http://www.selfadsi.org/ldap-filter.htm#HexFilter)

Comment: I think you're on the right track but the objectSid is not a string (it's and array of bytes) so using the `objectSid=*-513` filter doesn't work. If i could filter on this attribute it would work but a different syntax is needed.

Comment: So is it not possible ?